# How to get absolute coordinates in Safari on iOS?

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, mobile-safari, appium

I need to automate tapping on a specific bar in a bar chart that's stored inside of a canvas in a Safari browser on iOS. There's no useful information in the html to get this information unfortunately so I need to rely on hard coded coordinates in order to tap where I need to. On Android I can easily do this by turning on Pointer location in the developer settings - I can't seem to find the equivalent on iOS.

I found some javascript code snippets on the net that I could inject into the web inspector on safari to give me coordinates based on user touch but it seems like the coordinates I get there are relative to the web screen, I need absolute coordinates of the entire screen (if resolution is 1920x1080 I need to select which pixel to tap on).

```
$( document ).click(
            function( event ){

                // Client variables.
                console.log(
                    "clientX/Y: " +
                    event.clientX + ", " +
                    event.clientY
                );

                // Page variables. NOTE: These are the ones
                // that are officially supported by the
                // jQuery Event object.
                console.log(
                    "pageX/Y: " +
                    event.pageX + ", " +
                    event.pageY
                );

                // Hrule.
                console.log( "......" );

            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do this using code but I found out that you can easily get this information from taking a picture on your phone and then opening the file up in an image editing program. In my case I used Seashore.